# Question about $ \int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}} $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to answer this integral

$$ \int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}} $$

using the Reciprocal substitution method. How should I approach this?

Should I first rewrite or simplify the problem before I proceed to answer? if yes, someone please help me, an answer on this problem and as well an explanation would be so much appreciated too.

Thanks and advance and have a nice day.

Comment: Try substituting $x=\frac{1}{t}$...

Comment: As I wrote, one doesn't answer an integral. And please leave my tag edits alone, especially if you don't know what an improper integral is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem
$$\int \:\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}dx$$
Complete the square
$$\int \:\frac{1}{x\sqrt{\left(x+1\right)^2-2}}dx$$
Substitute
$$u=x+1\rightarrow \:\frac{du}{dx}=1\rightarrow \:du=dx$$
and
$$u=x+1\rightarrow \:x=u-1\rightarrow \:\:\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{u-1}$$
will becomes
$$\int \:\frac{1}{\left(u-1\right)\sqrt{u^2-2}}du$$
Perform trigonometric substitution
$$u=\sqrt{2}sec\left(v\right)\rightarrow v=arcsec\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}\right),du=\sqrt{2}sec\left(v\right)tan\left(v\right)dv$$
will becomes
$$\int \:\frac{\sqrt{2}sec\left(v\right)tan\left(v\right)}{\left(\sqrt{2}sec\left(v\right)−1\right)\sqrt{2sec^2\left(v\right)−2}}dv$$
Simplify by using
$$2sec^2\left(v\right)−2=2tan^2\left(v\right)$$
and becomes
$$\int \:\frac{sec\left(v\right)}{\sqrt{2}sec\left(v\right)−1}dv$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \:\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}sec\left(v\right)-1}dv+\frac{1}{2}\int \:dv$$
So, i think that you can take from here. For references, the final answer should be:
**$$\frac{2arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\sqrt{x-\sqrt{2}+1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{2}+1\:}}\right)}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}+c$$**

Answer (score 2):

With $h(x)= \sqrt{x^2+2x-1}$
\begin{align}
&\int \frac1{x\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}\ dx
=\int \frac{d( \frac{x-1}{h(x)})}{1+( \frac{x-1}{h(x)})^2}
 =\tan^{-1}\frac{x-1}{h(x)}+C
\end{align}

Comment: You destroyed the problem +1

Comment: @KamalSaleh - I may just have revealed its intent.

Comment: @Quanto Could you please elaborate a bit more on rewriting OP's integral? What suggested this step to you?

Answer (score 0):

Enforce an [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) to eliminate the square root and recover a trivial integral.

$$\int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^2 + 2x - 1}} = 2\int \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$

$$t=\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}-x \implies x = \frac12 \frac{1+t^2}{1-t} \implies dx = \left(\frac1{(1-t)^2}-\frac12\right)\,dt$$